# StackOverflow and Webmasters tags match

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-overflow

Should tags in Webmasters match the same tag name in StackOverflow, whenever applicable?

For example, I just noticed we have the [page-speed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-speed) tag in Webmasters, whilst the same tag is named [pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed) in StackOverflow.

What do you thing about renaming it in Webmasters or StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2):

The trend is to hyphenate tag names to show word breaks. I've started a [discussion on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108852/rename-pagespeed-to-page-speed) suggesting to change the tag on SO for consistency.